# android : Augmented reality support millions of image recognition

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I am developing an AR app that does image recognition. Now i need my app to support million of images. I was using vuforia. Vuforia free version has restriction on the number of images supported.  Is there any other library that is good in image recognition and supports huge number of images recognition

Comment: Just out of curiosity what is the volume of the images you want to be recognized? And related to this - isn't it applicable to be used several instances of the vuforia?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would suggest developing an Application which should support million of images using any kind of an SDK would be a performance hit. It will heavily consume the battery of the phone and make the Application to detect images very slow. 
Saying that I would suggest trying developing an Augmented Reality application which detects images using the Metaio SDK for Android platform. 
Refer their official web site http://www.metaio.com  for more info.

Comment: thanks for your response. I had checked metaio. I wanted a confirmation from their support team and asked a query in the forum. but no response so far. I read that they support images to be stored on web also. But i couldnt get further details on this like where exactly to be uploaded and any limit